# I can use this API on my emulator but not on my phone

Tags: android, http, request

I made an API from which I can get data using http.request module in dart. 'http://10.0.2.2:5000' is the url I'm using right now and it works just fine on my emulator but not on my phone, any idea why? Also does it make a difference if the phone is connected to the pc via USB? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`10.0.2.2` is the [loopback address](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aikz) used inside the network address space of Android Emulator, so only works wether you are using the emulator.

When you are using a physical device, the loopback address is `127.0.0.1`.

Try with 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' .

Of course, be sure to have `INTERNET` permissions.

Comment: Tried using the address you gave me but it throws the error:
Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111
(Also I added INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions)

Comment: are both server and client on the same phone? Or the server is on another device?

Comment: The server is on my pc

Comment: the loopback address only works wether both client and server are on the same device. In your case just follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device).